# JavaScript: Function that simulates CSS cubic-bezier()

Tags: javascript, css, animation, math

I am working on an animation library and have a variable that is incrementing from 0 to 1 (X axis in the graphic) while a timer is running. I now want to apply easing to my function in a similar fashion as the CSS function **cubic-bezier**.

[image]

My goal is that the y value doesn't increment linearly but instead is converted by the easing function. The function should look something like this:

```
function cubic-bezier(x, p0x, p0y, p1x, p1y){

   // Any suggestions for a formula or algorithm?

  return y;

};
```

I am not using any libraries and can't use any third party libraries on this project.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is the code I came up with. It is an adaption of this code jsfiddle.net/fQYsU.

```
var p1 = {0.5, 0.5};
var p2 = {0.5, 0.5};

cubic-bezier(t, p1, p2){

       var cX = 3 * (p1.x),
           bX = 3 * (p2.x - p1.x) - cX,
           aX = 1 - cX - bX;

       var cY = 3 * (p1.y - 1),
           bY = 3 * (p2.y - p1.y) - cY,
           aY = -1 - cY - bY;

       var x = (aX * Math.pow(t, 3)) + (bX * Math.pow(t, 2)) + (cX * t);
       var y = (aY * Math.pow(t, 3)) + (bY * Math.pow(t, 2)) + (cY * t) + 1;

       return {x: x, y: y};

   }

 var y = cubic-bezier(progress, p1, p2).y;
```

But the value it returns corresponds to x which might not be t. So I still don't know how to get the value at the correct position.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using this function http://jsfiddle.net/fQYsU/. But it changes the x value and is therefore not useful.

Comment: @Geuis None of the solutions I found work for my purpose.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696736 .